# How to train my brain.js model from a csv file?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network, predict, brain.js

I just learned brain.js and have been using it for quiet a while and now I have an idea for a project. I want to predict house prices for a given area in a specific city and the training data for this is inside a csv file. Now there's a couple of thousand examples in that file for It to learn from so copying/pasting all of it into the code would be a huge amount of work.

So can anyone please tell me a way of getting the neural network to learn from the csv file without me copy/pasting the data into the code?

Comment: You can use a data visualization library like D3.js.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a data visualization library like D3.js.

Here's the homepage for D3.js. You can find documentation, examples, and all the information that you might need about it over here:

https://d3js.org/

There are some alternatives as well though my personal recommendation would be D3.js because is super easy to use.

Refer to this page for alternatives:

https://www.g2.com/products/d3-js/competitors/alternatives